# How does SPF protect against email spoofing in case of a spoofer claiming the mail was relayed to him from a third party?

Tags: email, dns, spf

SPF records whitelist legitimate mailservers in the DNS record. Incoming mail servers reject mails whose outgoing mailserver is not on the whitelist. But what is preventing a spoofer from creating a mail and relaying it that he claims came from a whitelisted server? The server being handed that mail would look at the forged entry of the mail and it would match up with the whitelist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SPF is only concerned with the (apparent) sender address and the currently connected SMTP client.

[RFC 7208 says](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7208#section-4) about a imaginary function `check_host` that verifies SPF:

```
The check_host() function takes these arguments:

   <ip>     - the IP address of the SMTP client that is emitting
              the mail, either IPv4 or IPv6.

   <domain> - the domain that provides the sought-after authorization
              information; initially, the domain portion of the
              "MAIL FROM" or "HELO" identity.

   <sender> - the "MAIL FROM" or "HELO" identity.
```

Only the “last” relaying MTA has to be authorized in the SPF rules. Everything else doesn’t count.

Comment: As a result: if relays use the original 'MAIL FROM' when relaying, they fail the check even if they're legitimate; if relays use _their own_ domain in 'MAIL FROM', they pass the SPF check with no problem, but fail DMARC alignment checks instead...